# Using Bootstraps data-spy and data-toggle on a button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to have a button not only toggle a hidden accordian but also, have the page scroll to that section? This is the code I have so far. I have the navigation working great, was wondering what I was missing to get that button to display text and scroll to the top of it.

Thank you.

Here's a [Codepen](http://www.bootply.com/hpmLFgI6sH) that has everything that I'm using. I was wondering if I could get some help?

And my HTML markup

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="scroll">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6" href="#top"><img src="/img/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Rhino Group Logo"></a>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1 visible-xs phoneIcon text-center"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></div>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-bar" class="navbar-toggle collapsed col-xs-2">
          <span class="sr-only"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse top-pull-right" id="navigation-bar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="caps"><a href="#Services">services</a></li>
          <li class="caps"><a href="#Portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
          <li class="caps"><a href="#Contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="about-background">
<section class="about"> <!-- begin about -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" data-spy="scroll">
      <h1 class="slogan text-center">The <span class="red">POWER</span> of the <span class="blue">WEB</span></h1>
      <p class="text-center col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1  ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

      <button class="read-more text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#aboutUs">
        <h4 class="caps">continue reading</h4>
      </button>
        <div class="collapse panel-body col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12" id="aboutUs">
          <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis ante vulputate, tincidunt est nec, porttitor lorem. Praesent id nisi leo. Nunc imperdiet lacus quis condimentum tempus. Vestibulum mollis, magna at fermentum consequat, turpis elit suscipit libero, ac tincidunt purus nibh vitae massa. Aenean eleifend ipsum aliquam est euismod, non convallis ante mollis. Sed maximus dui sit amet dui vestibulum mattis. 
          </p> 
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section> <!-- end about -->
```

Comment: I have tried to do this multiple times applying data-target on several elements including the root div. As it's not ON the example, doesn't indicate that I didn't "try." Thanks for the criticism.

Comment: It's Bootstrap, what's to code from scratch? I'm not asking to write jQuery, I'm asking if my html code is correct, or am I missing some elements to the HTML that Bootstrap utilizes. If you check the codepen link I supplied, there's my jQuery, theres my CSS, theres my HTML with my "failed" code.

Comment: I was rather poliet, however your inital comment and assumptions were rather cruel.

I am unsure of what you did, as this did not answer my question. I understand free help, but you have initally since the start, ridiculed my attempts to debug my own code.

Comment: Also, I'm not focusing on the navigation. In my normal coding, that works just fine. I am talking about the button that says Continue Reading, toggling the content to appear, but then scroll up to display the content, for mobile users as the space is constrained

Comment: I resolved my own issue by reading through the jQuery and finding a conflict between the href and the data-toggle. I had to rewrite the jQuery and impliment my own accordian so they would play nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is this here. I wasn't exactly properly calling to the href and it was conflicting with the data-target. By removing the data-target and writing in my own collapse accordian, the second example, I was able to get around the issue.

Running this line here with my initial example:

jQuery:

```
function scrollNav() {
  $('.navbar a').click(function(){  
     //Toggle Class
     $(".active").removeClass("active");      
     $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
     var theClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $('.'+theClass).parent('li').addClass('active');
    //Animate
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - 61
      }, 1000);
        return false;
    });
    $('.scrollTop a').scrollTop();
    }


function scrollReadMoreBtn() {
  $(' #readMoreBtn').on('click', function(){  
     $('#aboutUs').slideDown('slow/400/fast');
    //Animate
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( '#aboutUs' ).offset().top - 61
      }, 1000);
        return false;
    });
    $('.scrollTop a').scrollTop();
    }
```

With this HTML

```
<div class="about-background">
    <section class="about"> <!-- begin about -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <h1 class="slogan text-center">The <span class="red">POWER</span> of the <span class="blue">WEB</span></h1>
          <p class="text-center col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1  ">Lorem Ipsum</p>

          <button href="#readMore" class="read-more text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" id="readMoreBtn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" >
            <h4 class="caps">continue reading</h4>
          </button>
            <div class="collapse panel-body col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12" id="aboutUs" name="readMore">
              <p class="text-justify">Lorem Ipsum content </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
```